# how can i find Object data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I have multiple object values ​​called items in the `TodoItem` component in FlatList.
also, I have a single object value called `itemtow`

What I'm trying to do is to put the item object value that matches the item object's id value and the `itemtow's CommentId` value into the result constant.

this is my data and code

item data

```
    item: {id: 163, content: "부모1", createdAt: "2021-03-19T16:23:20.000Z", updatedAt: "2021-03-19T16:23:20.000Z", UserId: 1, …}

    item: {id: 164, content: "부모2", createdAt: "2021-03-19T16:23:23.000Z", updatedAt: "2021-03-19T16:23:23.000Z", UserId: 1, …}

    item: {id: 165, content: "부모3", createdAt: "2021-03-19T16:23:38.000Z", updatedAt: "2021-03-19T16:23:38.000Z", UserId: 2, …}

    item: {id: 166, content: "부모4", createdAt: "2021-03-19T16:23:41.000Z", updatedAt: "2021-03-19T16:23:41.000Z", UserId: 2, …}
```

itemtow data

```
    itemtow: {id: 268,  CommentId: 166, content: "부모4", active: "1", createdAt: "2021-03-19T16:23:41.000Z", updatedAt: "2021-03-20T05:56:24.000Z", …}
```

expected result data it would be

```
    expected result =  {id: 166, content: "부모4", createdAt: "2021-03-19T16:23:41.000Z", updatedAt: "2021-03-19T16:23:41.000Z", UserId: 2, …}
```

this is my code

(todoList.js)

```
    const TodoList = ({item}) => {

      return (

        <>
        <FlatList
          data={singlePost?.Comments}
          keyExtractor={(item) => String(item.id)}
          
          ListEmptyComponent={<EmptyItem />}
          renderItem={({item}) => (
            <TodoItem
              item={item}
              itemtow={itemtow}
            />
          )}
        />
      </>
      );
    };

    export default TodoList;
```

(TodoItem.js)

```
    const TodoItem = ({item ,itemtow}) => {


      const result = item.filter((v) => v.id === itemtow.CommentId);

      console.log("result:",result);

      return (

      )
```

how can i fix my code? i've tried use filter but it doesn't work .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `TodoItem` component, `item` is a single element (object) from the array `singlePost?.Comments` which you passed to [FlatList](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist).

So, you simply need to check the `item.id` against `itemRow.CommentId`:

```
const TodoItem = ({ item, itemRow }) => {

  const matched = item.id === itemRow.CommentId
  console.log('matched? ', matched, item)

  return <>...</>
}
```

Also, you may want to pass `[]` as fallback value to `FlatList`:

```
<FlatList
  data={singlePost?.Comments ?? []}
  ...
```

Comment: Assuming, it is `itemRow` not `itemtow` (Typo).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the `filter` method is working fine.

```js
const items = [
  {id: 163, content: "부모1", createdAt: "2021-03-19T16:23:20.000Z", updatedAt: "2021-03-19T16:23:20.000Z", UserId: 1},
  {id: 164, content: "부모2", createdAt: "2021-03-19T16:23:23.000Z", updatedAt: "2021-03-19T16:23:23.000Z", UserId: 1},
  {id: 165, content: "부모3", createdAt: "2021-03-19T16:23:38.000Z", updatedAt: "2021-03-19T16:23:38.000Z", UserId: 2},
  {id: 166, content: "부모4", createdAt: "2021-03-19T16:23:41.000Z", updatedAt: "2021-03-19T16:23:41.000Z", UserId: 2}
];

const itemRow = {id: 268,  CommentId: 166, content: "부모4", active: "1", createdAt: "2021-03-19T16:23:41.000Z", updatedAt: "2021-03-20T05:56:24.000Z"};

const result = items.filter(v => v.id === itemRow.CommentId);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: no it doesn;t work as i said that items value is not array  but object